# Is there a field with finitely many abelian extensions, that is neither separably closed nor real closed?

Tags: galois-theory, fields, class-field-theory

If $K$ has only finitely many Galois extensions, then $K$ must be either separably closed or real closed. Are there any other fields whose abelianizations are finite extensions (i.e. whose absolute Galois groups have finite abelianizations)?

Comment: The maximal solvable extension of, say, $\mathbb Q$ has only one abelian extension (viz. itself), but is not separably closed or real closed.

Comment: Oh, right. That is obvious in retrospect. Thanks.

Comment: This suggests the followup question of whether there are any fields $K$ not real closed that have at least 1 but only finitely many proper abelian extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another example, which also answers the "followup question":
Let $K$ be the field of Laurent series over $\mathbb{R}$.  Its absolute Galois group is the infinite profinite dihedral group  $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}\rtimes(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, where the action is by inversion.  This group is the free profinite product of two groups of order $2$. Its abelianization is therefore $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$.  In particular, $K$ has the desired property.